# Did Djokovic receive judgments from Australia's Federal Circuit Court, then Federal Court, more speedily than average?

Tags: australia

I quote Paul Daly, [University Research Chair in Administrative Law & Governance at the University of Ottawa (Faculty of Law, Common Law Section)](https://www.administrativelawmatters.com/paul-daly/bio/). [Educated at University College Cork (BCL, LLM), the University of Pennsylvania Law School (LLM) and the University of Cambridge (PhD), he was previously Senior Lecturer in Public Law, University of Cambridge and, before that, Associate Professor and Associate Dean at the Faculté de droit, Université de Montréal.](https://www.administrativelawmatters.com/paul-daly/bio/) [Novak Djokovic and the Value of Administrative Law](https://www.administrativelawmatters.com/blog/2022/01/15/novak-djokovic-and-the-value-of-administrative-law/)

> Hardly any immigrant has Djokovic’s resources and will receive the Cadillac justice he has been receiving.

I am not referring to Djokovic's wealth that lets him afford Australian solicitors and Queen's Counsel barristers. I am asking about the Australian courts' treatment of him. How did the Australian justice system furnish him  "the Cadillac justice he has been receiving"?

For example, was his case heard by the Federal Circuit and Family Court, then the Federal Court, more speedily than usual?

Comment: FWIW, the entire resume of the person you are quoting doesn't really need to be in the body text of the question, particularly if the links establish that fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Courts do prioritise cases that need urgent resolution, regardless of the parties' nobility or net worth. The process of prioritising is not open to the public though: it is hard to prove that nobility/net worth do *not* play a role.

In any event, the Djokovic's cases *did* need urgent resolution for obvious reasons: he had his visa cancelled and was liable for immediate detention and expedited deportation. As to whether anyone else needed justice more urgent than *he* got it — go figure.

Comment: It's hard to see how his case was more urgent than any other immigrant's... So it certainly appears that fame & money can buy your way to the top of the queue in Australia (as it probably does in many other countries too).

Comment: @brhans He wasn't an immigrant, and this question is not about the general queue of people wishing their Australian visa problems  resolved.
 "Case" in this case means an actual  case filed with the court. I don't know where we can see the list of cases of visitors who have just landed in Australia, got their visa cancelled _and_ applied to have that overturned through the court.

Comment: @brhans In this case, the proximity of the tennis tournement could help justify the speed. If he were allowed to enter Australia, telling him after he had not been able to play the tounament would have cause Djokovic significant damages; OTOH letting him play only to deport him later would have rendered the issue moot.

Comment: @SJuan76 sure - I don't disagree with any of that. However I could construct a similar set of circumstances where Mr Nobody has arrived in Australia to attend some event which, to him, is vitally important, potentially life-changing, and occurs within the next few days after arrival. He has arrived in the nominally good-faith expectation of being allowed to enter, but due to whatever circumstances his entry got denied. I think the chances of Mr Nobody getting these expedited hearings is vanishingly small - even in the unlikely event that he had enough money to pay for solicitors & barristers.

Comment: It also bears noting that while the government or the law or the judiciary can set some general standards regarding how expeditiously cases are handled, some of it is just luck of the draw. Some judges are more diligent and prompt in doing their jobs than others, and at micromanaged level, pretty much nobody is in a good position to tell a judge once assigned to a case how quickly or slowly that case will be handled. This is true in pretty much every court system and I have seen judges confronted with ordinary cases nearly identical to each other handle them at very different speeds.

Comment: @brhans you may be right about Mr Nobody's chances being vanishingly small, and you may be wrong. There is no evidence either way as far as I am aware.